# Can I use a stamp to make mobile deposits for my LLC?

Tags: banking, check, deposits, endorsement

I have an LLC called "MrPeanut LLC." I am currently depositing all checks with a signed endorsement via my bank's mobile app as such:

> *John A. Smith*, Managing Member
>
> For mobile deposit to MyBank

I would rather buy a custom stamp since they are a lot of small checks. However, I'm not sure what information to include and whether the bank will accept it. I'm thinking this should suffice:

> For Deposit Only
>
> MrPeanut LLC
>
> For mobile deposit to MyBank

But this seems a bit redundant and I'm not sure if there's a simpler way to create this stamp. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The best answer to this question will come directly from your bank. Have you asked them?

Comment: How do you sign them now?  Make that into a stamp.  It is a good time saving hack.

Comment: Why not "MrPeanut LLC / For mobile deposit to MyBank"?

Answer (score 1):

Without a location tag, I'm going to assume the United States. According to [Section 3-401(b) of the Uniform Commercial Code](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/3/3-401) (my emphasis):

> A signature may be made (i) manually **or by means of a device or machine**, and (ii) by the use of any name, including a trade or assumed name, or by a word, mark, or symbol executed or adopted by a person with present intention to authenticate a writing.

Based on a plain reading of this, you can use a stamp in place of a manual signature. And part (ii) of that same section makes it clear that you can use "MrPeanut, LLC", instead of "John A. Smith", under the "a trade or assumed name" phrase.

Ultimately, you want to check with your bank. With the banks that I've dealt with, I've had to notify them of my intent to use of a signature stamp to *sign* checks. (They make a note on the signature card to indicate that a stamped signature is acceptable.) But I've not had to get approval to use a stamp to *endorse* the back of a check for depositing. They did, however, suggest that I include the account number in the stamp. (I don't know what additional security this provides.) In my case, the endorsement stamp looks like this:

```
For Deposit Only
My Full Name
Account #123456
```

(This was before mobile deposits were a thing. Nowadays, I'd make it start with "For mobile deposit only at MyBank".)

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use a stamp. In fact, in some cases banks add a stamp automatically to your mobile deposit - I know this because I deposited my own checks from one account into another and saw the stamp magically appear when the check image was posted.

When I opened the first account for my LLC, the bank gave me a free order of checks and with it, as a bonus, a free stamp for deposits that I now use to do mobile deposits.